# Python - How to create an instance of a class in a separate file

Tags: python, file, class, module, instance

I'm trying to create a new instance of the class "player" (in Player.py) from a file called Login.py

```
    import Player
    pfile = "data/players/" + username
    s = shelve.open(pfile)
    s(username = Player.player(username, password, False))
```

And from that I get:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'player'
```

I want to be able to create the object and place it in a dictionary where its key is the username of the player, what am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Are you certain that the module `Player.py` *has* anything named `player` in it? Also check if you imported the correct `Player.py`; perhaps you have more than one. Add `print Player.__file__` below the import line to check.

Comment: `s(username = Player.player(username, password, False))` doesn't even look valid

Comment: @JakobBowyer: That's the next problem the OP will run into. For now, Python assumes `username` is a keyword argument.

Comment: What is wrong with s(username = Player.player(username, password, False))? I will change username to user. Thanks

Comment: I fixed the dictionary syntax, now I have a shelf error haha, thanks for the help.

Comment: `shelve` instances are like dictionaries, so to access its contents I would think you'd want to write `s[username]` to retrieve the data value associated with a particular player based on their name. See [example](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html#example) in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your class is Player this would mean that to reference it you should do something like this

```
import Player
my_player = Player.Player(username, password, False)
```

You should also look at this line

```
s(username = Player.player(username, password, False))
```

Im not sure its valid and will work as Martijn pointed out, python will treat username as a keyword argument

Comment: Nope, it's definitely lowercase